# Error al intentar crear PDF tipo PDF_A_3A con iTextSharp y C# **Marked**

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itextsharp

Buen día.

Llevo días tratando de solucionar el siguiente error: **Document catalog dictionary shall include a MarkInfo dictionary whose entry Marked shall have a value of true**, [image: error]
este error me aparece cuando trato de crear un pdf tipo PDF_A_3A en C# con iTextSharp, aquí parte del código que estoy utilizando,

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
        document.SetMargins(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);

        // Create PdfAWriter with PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_3B option if you
        // want to get a PDF/A-3b compliant document.
        PdfAWriter writer = PdfAWriter.GetInstance(document,
                    new FileStream(@"C:\Users\SandroEstivenPinedaS\Documents\pdfExport\Formato_electronico_FPOB_pdfa-3.pdf", FileMode.Create),
                    PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_3A);
        // Create XMP metadata. It's a PDF/A requirement.
        writer.CreateXmpMetadata();


        document.Open();

        // Set output intent. PDF/A requirement.
        ICC_Profile icc = ICC_Profile
                .GetInstance(
                       @"C:\Users\SandroEstivenPinedaS\Documents\pdfExport\prueba_pdf_formulario\sRGB_CS_profile.icm");
        writer.SetOutputIntents("Custom", "", "http://www.color.org",
                "sRGB IEC61966-2.1", icc);


        // Creating PDF/A-3 compliant attachment.
        PdfDictionary parameters = new PdfDictionary();
        parameters.Put(PdfName.MODDATE, new PdfDate());




        PdfFileSpecification fileSpec = PdfFileSpecification.FileEmbedded(
                writer, @"C:\Users\SandroEstivenPinedaS\Documents\pdfExport\prueba_pdf_formulario\xml_asofondos.xml",
                "xml_asofondos.xml", null, "application/xml", parameters, 0);
        fileSpec.Put(new PdfName("AFRelationship"), new PdfName("Data"));
        writer.AddFileAttachment("xml_asofondos.xml", fileSpec);

        PdfArray array = new PdfArray();
        array.Add(fileSpec.Reference);


        writer.ExtraCatalog.Put(new PdfName("AF"), array);
        writer.ExtraCatalog.Put(new PdfName("MarkInfo"), new PdfBoolean(true));

        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(@"C:\Users\SandroEstivenPinedaS\Documents\pdfExport\prueba_pdf_formulario\Formato_electronico_FPOB_pdfa-2.pdf");

        //document.Add
        for (int i = 1; i <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, i);

            document.Add(iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(page));
        }

        //document.CloseDocument();
        document.Close();
        writer.Close();
```

El error aparece cuando se ejecuta la linea de `document.Close();`.
y solo ocurre cuando utilizo el valor de `PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_3A`, con los demás valores funciona correctamente,